# solana-test-validator airdrop failed

Tags: solana, solana-cli

I'm trying to setup my [Solana dev environment](https://docs.solana.com/getstarted/local) and I've run into an issue with the initial airdrop.
The `solana-test-validator` runs and produces output. However, when I run `solana airdrop 1` I get the following error:

> Error: airdrop request failed. This can happen when the rate limit is reached.

My config file looks like this:

```
---
json_rpc_url: "http://localhost:8899"
websocket_url: ""
keypair_path: "C:/Users/dan/.config/solana/id.json"
address_labels:
  "11111111111111111111111111111111": System Program
commitment: confirmed
```

I also found this in the logs:

```
[2022-10-23T03:22:02.386989700Z INFO  solana_faucet::faucet] request_airdrop_transaction: faucet_addr=0.0.0.0:9900 id=2jXbinTJ1kegWszgckb3i2CZ4pK
6Edu3M8YVMgE2tPxm lamports=1000000000 blockhash=HG5nHdGJ9EWSHXdThrpGYfdCP5UfDPXkXwRYaTvni5vr
[2022-10-23T03:22:02.388016300Z INFO  solana_rpc::rpc::rpc_full] request_airdrop_transaction failed: IoError(Os { code: 10049, kind: AddrNotAvail
able, message: "The requested address is not valid in its context." })
```

Any assistance is appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: When you use `solana-test-validator` it automagically put's TONs of SOL into your wallet. Also, you have to have the `solana-test-validator` running.

Comment: I confirm that I have the `solana-test-validator` running when trying to do the airdrop. I also ran `solana balance` and its output is `0`. Are you saying that I don't need to worry about this because it will grant me `SOL` whenever I need it?

I'm just following the [setup guide](https://docs.solana.com/getstarted/local) and that's where it said I need to do the airdrop thing.